# Qt app version autoincrement with custom target in .pro

Tags: qt, versioning

I'd like to autoincrement my projects version on every build. I have a simple program that regenerates a header file with updated version. I'd like to call this program on every build. It can be done quite simply in single projects (add a build step), but with subdirs project is quite more complicated.

I've read several topics on the matter, and all suggest to use custom target in .pro files. My main reference is [this blog post](http://qtcreator.blogspot.it/2009/10/generating-automatic-version-numbers.html).

I've made several test, but I'm not able to run a custom command during build. For testing purpose, I have this code in .pro file

```
versiontarget.target = version.h
versiontarget.command = LaunchTM
versiontarget.depends = FORCE
PRE_TARGETDEPS += version.h
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += versiontarget
```

Here I'm using `LaunchTM` as a command for testing purpose (I'm on Windows; this command launches the Task Manager). The command is never executed, nor when I launch rebuild, nor when I build after an edit. I've also noticed that there is no reference about `versiontarget` or `LaunchTM` in the generated Makefiles

Am I missing something?

When I'll be able to launch the test command, it's not a problem to switch to the correct command.

Comment: You do exactly one build per application version?

Comment: @ddriver I'm not sure I've understood your comment. BTW, I'd like to increment a version field (e.g. build) on every debug build, than increment another version field (e.g. minor version) on every release build (this will reset the previous version field (build)). I also add a revision field given current VCS revision number. So yes, I generate a new version number on every build.

Comment: Is the "version.h" in you HEADERS ?

Comment: @Rinold Yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo in "versiontarget.command**s**" - the bold "s" is missing in your example code. It seems qmake doesn't check it and just ignores it, threating it like the "command**s**" are empty.

The other way that might also work is (first is kind of pre-defined thing related to *first* target specified in project, thus you extra target should be executed before main, as it it is in *depends* of it):

```
versiontarget.commands = LaunchTM
first.depends = $(first) versiontarget
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first versiontarget
```

**UPD**: *Any idea about how to run the custom target only if the build actually takes place?*

There are several solutions, AFAIK:

1. If you version auto-increment script will produce bumped version to some, for example, header file, that will be included and used in your project - just ignore it. Code changes should trigger app build then.
2. Use the [QMAKE_POST_LINK](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-post-link) instead of QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS, e.g.:

   QMAKE_POST_LINK += LaunchTM

It should be run only if your build triggers linking (app changes).

Note: That way you should keep in mind that the version IN app would be less that version you store somewhere, as it is triggered after compilation. However, continuously, it should give you the version differentiation anyway.

3. If you are using the VCS (version control) you can configure commit / push (if git used) hooks, and increment the version that way. The benefit of such solution is that you can configure your version changes committed to repository automatically, and if you get the code from repository and build it - the version would be set correctly, as it would be related to actual code changes (commits) not the count of builds you done locally.

Comment: Damn... I'm gonna test it on monday. Shame on me if it's really just a typo!

Comment: Ok, it really was just the typo. BTW, I've noted that the command will be called on every build, even if source code is not edited (make exits with "nothing to be done"). Any idea about how to run the custom target only if the build actually takes place?

Comment: Oh.. I've updated the answer with some solutions, that may fit your purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I think that QMAKE_POST_LINK is a really good solution! Side notes: 1) One can use a header file without triggering a rebuild by not listing it in the HEADERS section in .pro 2) To be more clear, the use of QMAKE_POST_LINK is an alternative to the use of custom targets 3) I made some test with VCS hooks; the problem, again, is managing multiple subprojects (in the new commit, maybe just some subprojects have been rebuild); fresh thought, one can use diff on compilation outputs to tell if a project have been rebuild or not; will think about this the next days...

Comment: Ignore my (1) note, too. Looks like qmake will add all #include-d files in the make process, so it is not enough to remove them from the HEADERS list